# Visual Studio 2010 RC + ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, visual-studio-2010

Now that [ASP.NET MVC 2 is out](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en), I tried to install it on my development machine, which already has Visual Studio 2010 RC installed and I got this error message during installation

> Component Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 has failed to install with the following error message:
>   "A different version of ASP.NET MVC 2 is already installed on your system. Please uninstall this version before proceeding with this install."

Sure enough, the MVC 2 release notes state:

> Note   Because Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 RC share a component of ASP.NET MVC 2, installing the ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM release on a computer where Visual Studio 2010 RC is also installed is not supported.

So my question is, though officially unsupported, if I uninstall VS 2010 RC, install MVC 2 then re-install VS 2010 RC, might this work? And would I then be able to target MVC 2 in VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/10/installing-asp-net-mvc-2-rc-2-on-visual-studio.aspx.  This is unsupported, but the same general steps should work.